# Populating a list and Random select item in Unity

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity script PlayerController.cs with game loginc and MyCity.cs in which a public class for MyCity is defined.

My goal is to populate the List in the PlayerController.cs.

The list contains cities and their x,y,z Vector3 coordinates.

My PlayerController script should randomly pick one city out of my list and use that in my SetTargetCity function so it can create a new gameobject with the appropriate Vector3 coordinates.

I am getting this error:

'The name mycities' does not exist in the current document'

What am I doing wrong? creating a public var for mycities doesn't do the trick....

MyCity.cs contains the following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyCity
{
public string name;
public float xcor;
public float zcor;
public float ycor;

public MyCity(string newName, float newXcor, float newZcor, float newYcor)
{
    name = newName;
    xcor = newXcor;
    zcor = newZcor;
    ycor = newYcor;
}
 }
```

Then the PlayerController script looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
public float speed;
public float smooth = 2.0F;
public GUIText countText;
public GUIText targetCity;
private int count;
public GameObject cityPrefab;


void Start()
{


    List<MyCity> mycities = new List<MyCity>();

    mycities.Add( new MyCity("Maastricht", -5F, 3F, -1F )); 
    mycities.Add( new MyCity("Breda", -6F, 3F, -2F));
    mycities.Add( new MyCity("Amsterdam", -2F, 3F, 4F));


//WHAT ELSE DO I NEED  TO DO TO THE ABOVE LIST SO THAT
//THE BELOW FUNCTION void SetTargetCity () WILL WORK? 

    // scoring points & display on screen (works)
    count = 0;
    SetCountText ();

}

// Player Movement (works)
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    Vector3 moveDirection= new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0, moveVertical);  
    if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero){
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection * -1);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, newRotation,  Time.deltaTime * smooth);

        rigidbody.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }

}
    // Score points by flying into city game object (works), switch off that target city game object (works), get new target city...(no idea)
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "City") {
                    other.gameObject.SetActive (false); 

        count = count + 1;

        SetCountText ();
        SetTargetCity ();
            }
}

void SetCountText ()
{
    countText.text = "Passengers Picked up: " + count.ToString();
}




   // BELOW IS WHERE THINGS GO WRONG.

    void SetTargetCity ()
{
    var randomCity = mycities[0];
targetCity.text = "Fly to: " + randomCity.name.ToString();

GameObject instancedCity=(GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(cityPrefab);
instancedCity.transform.position=new Vector3(randomCity.xcor,randomCity.ycor,randomCity.zcor);
}



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the `myCities` outside of your `Start` method and initialize it like this:

```
List<MyCity> mycities;
void Start()
{
   mycities = new List<MyCity>();
   ...
}
```

Comment: All i need to do now is find the proper Vector3 coordinates for each city....I placed objects in my scene at the right position above a plane...in the Unity inspector, these objects have XYZ coordinates in their Transform property....but these are apparently not the same as the required Vector3 coordinates in my scene...any idea?

Comment: Ignore that last comment, got the right Vector. My objects were not relative to the world.